Screen privacy inverted
It seems that the "Screen Privacy" setting in Ubuntu 24.04 is inverted with respect to the actual condition.
When, on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon gen 11, I press Fn + D the screen gets darker from aside, but:

the GNOME popup says that Privacy Screen is disabled
The screen privacy setting in GNOME Settings is set to "disabled"
the file /proc/acpi/ibm/lcdshadow shows a "1" status. [This is right, I guess]

Quite the opposite when I press Fn + D again.
Furthermore it seems that the Privacy setting itself does not effectively control the setting; it only gets updated when I use the keyboard shortcut.
